# How to populate model's new fields from OneToOneField in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

In Django 3.1.2, I would like to copy data in a OneToOneField to multiple fields.

I want to change

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='b_a')
```

to

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
```

while keeping existing data.

Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 0):

step1

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='b_a')
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
```

step2

```
makemigrations
migrate
def sync():
    for i in B.objects.all():
        i.name = i.a.name
        i.description = i.a.description
        i.save()
```

step3

```
change model B

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
```

step4

```
makemigrations
migrate
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to sync in step 2 please?

Comment: @YifanAi please refresh ，This is a demo. You need to pay attention to the performance when using it